# Разграничить один и тот же товар в корзине

Tags: php, javascript, json, yii2, cookie

Делаю сайты для 3 ресторанов, все они расположены на разных поддоменах, товар добавляется в куки и отображается в корзине, то есть можно добавить товар с ресторана №1 и он будет виден в корзине других ресторанов, проблема в том, что там есть очень много одинаковых товаров, в админке добавляется 1 товар и он может быть отображен во всех ресторанах,  как мне разграничить их в корзине, чтобы было видно с какого сайта пришел товар. Или это можно как-то на js сделать?
 На js получается разграничивать разные товары -

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $parent_item_bav =  $('.item_cart0').parent('tbody').parent('table').parent('div'),
    $parent_item_jar = $('.item_cart1').parent('tbody').parent('table').parent('div'),
    $parent_item_erm = $('.item_cart2').parent('tbody').parent('table').parent('div');

    $parent_item_bav.prepend('<h2>Ресторан Бавария</h2>');
    $parent_item_jar.prepend('<h2>Ресторан Жар-Птица</h2>');
    $parent_item_erm.prepend('<h2>Ресторан Эрмитаж</h2>');
  });
```

А как это сделать с товарами у которых одинаковые id?

Код контроллера корзины -

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Вывод корзины
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $cart = Cart::get();
        if ($cart->count == 0) {
            return $this->render('empty');
        } else {
            return $this->render('index', [
                'content' => $cart
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Добавить товар
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionAdd()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            /* @var $item \app\models\Product */
            $item = Product::findOne($_POST['id']);

            return json_encode(
                Cart::add([
                    'id' => $_POST['id'],
                    'count' => 1,
                    'price' => $item->price,
                    'str1' => $item->str1,
                    'restaurantNum' => 1,
                    'restaurant' => 'Заказ с ресторана Жар-птица',
                    'content' => [
                        'name' => $item->name,
                        'image' => 'http://rest.alazameb.beget.tech/uploads/img/' . $item->image,
                        'url' => $_POST['url']
                    ]
                ]),

                JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
            );
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не найдено.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Удалить товар
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionDelete()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return json_encode(Cart::delete($_POST['id']), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не найдено.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Удалить все товары
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionRemove()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return json_encode(Cart::remove(), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не найдено.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Изменить товар
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return json_encode(Cart::update($_POST['id'], (int)$_POST['count']), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не найдено.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Изменить товар
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionGet()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return json_encode(Cart::get(), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не найдено.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Оформление заказа
     *
     * @return string|\yii\web\Response
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function actionCheck()
    {
        if (Cart::get()->count !== 0) {
            $form = new CheckForm();
            if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $form->validate()) {
                $form->check();
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('check-order');
                return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
            } else {
                return $this->render('check', [
                    'model' => $form,
                    'cart' => Cart::get()
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Не найдено.');
        }
    }
}
```

Код корзины view -

```
<div class="wrap_cart">


    <section id="contant" class="onlyforcart" style="">
        <a id="main-content">X</a>

        <h1 class="page-header">Ваш заказ</h1>

        <div class="region region-content">
            <section id="block-system-main" class="block block-system clearfix">


                <div class="view view-commerce-cart-form view-id-commerce_cart_form view-display-id-default view-dom-id-cbaa018c2c2ab5ac7a6410b5fe5ad95b jquery-once-3-processed">



                    <div class="view-content">
                        <div class="commerce-line-item-views-form"><div id="dc-cart-ajax-form-wrapper"><form action="/cart" method="post" id="views-form-commerce-cart-form-default" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-BuMnhXlCP8SKma_h5bthYm841vMbViD9PNcx-Xd2Zak">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="Yqj71aD5Bm-szOGiRZujYk7i52mFkrIfHkfefncPZu8">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="views_form_commerce_cart_form_default">


                            <?php                                   
                            $array = array();
                            foreach ($content->items as $key => $item){
                                $array[$item['str1']][$key] = $item;
                            }
                            ?>  

<a href="" class="clear cart-remove">Очистить корзину</a>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="open_mobile">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">из "Баварии"</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">из "Жар-Птицы"</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">из "Эрмитажа"</a></li>
</ul>
    <?php foreach ($array as $keys):?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="views-table cols-6 table table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th class="views-field views-field-nothing">Название
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price views-align-left">
                        Цена          </th>
                        <th class="views-field views-field-edit-quantity">
                        Кол-во          </th>

                        <th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-left">
                        Итого          </th>
                        <th class="views-field views-field-edit-delete">
                        Удалить          </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach ($keys as $item): ?>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr class="odd views-row-first item_cart<?= $item['restaurantNum'] ?>">

                            <td class="views-field views-field-nothing">
                                <img src="<?= $item['content']['image'] ?>" width="120" height="80">
                                <br>
                            </td><td><?= $item['content']['name'] ?></td>
                            <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price views-align-left price">
                                <?= $item['price']?> руб.          </td>
                                <td class="views-field views-field-edit-quantity">
                                    <?= $item['count'] ?>
                                </td>

                                <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-left price">
                                    <span class=""><?= $item['price'] *  $item['count'] /*- ceil((($item['price'] *  $item['count']) * 7) / 100)*/ ?></span>           </td>
                                    <td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash cart-delete" data-cart="<?= $item['id'] ?>" title="Удалить"></span></td>


                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>








                    </table>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>    
        </div>


        <div class="line-item-summary">
            <div class="line-item-quantity">
                <span class="line-item-quantity-raw"><?= $item['count'] ?></span> <span class="line-item-quantity-label">товаров</span>
            </div>
            <div class="line-item-total">
                <p>Сумма:<span class="notsale"><?=  $content->notsale ?></span> руб. </p>
                <span class="line-item-total-label">При заказе с сайта скидка 7%, Итого:</span> <span class="line-item-total-raw cart-price-order"><?=  $content->price /*- ceil(($content->price * 7) / 100)*/ ?> руб.</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="links list-inline"><li class="line-item-summary-checkout first last"><a href="/checkout" rel="nofollow">Оформление заказа</a></li>
            </ul></div>
            <div class="form-actions commerce-line-item-actions form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-actions">
                <?= Html::a('Оформить заказ', ['order/check'], ['class' => 'btn btn-default form-submit']) ?>
            </div></div></form></div></div><div class="attachment"><div class="views-summary"><a href="#" id="dc-cart-ajax-views-form-commerce-cart-form-default">&nbsp;</a></div></div>    </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Сайт - http://bavaria.alazameb.beget.tech/products

Comment: у cookie можно установить зону видимости, например в нужный вам поддомен =)

Comment: не совсем понял, мне нужно, чтобы товары были видны на всех поддоменах, но просто было разграничение,  по типо если товары были добавлены с ресторана №1, над ними заголовок появлется - ресторан №1

Comment: Тогда собственно вопрос возникает, в чем у вас проблема? код содержит указание ресторана, вы не можете вывести его на экран или в чем сложность?

Comment: нет все выводится, но если я добавлю тот же товар с другого ресторана, он отображается в одном блоке,  а мне надо чтобы один и тот же товар был в разных в блоках, в зависимости от того, с которого ресторана он был добавлен

Comment: А если попробовать использовать массив, с соответствующим маркером (того или иного ресторана)

Comment: да я что-то похожее сделал, вроде работает, так как там одинаковые id, я просто при записи в куки прибавлял значение к id и теперь одинаковые товары позиционируются как абсолютно разные